# Which university has a good postgraduate DevOps program?

Tags: learning

I am looking for a university that has a good PhD program in theoretical DevOps topics. Especially any program that is trying to advance the beyond Deming's Theory of Profound Knowledge, Goldratt's Theory of Constraints and other related topics. Do you know a professor specifically interested in running a program like that and currently doing advanced research in this field?

I have found some companies, which do consulting in this area and try to push it forward, but I am having problems to find some program in academic setting with sufficient credibility.

Comment: Chiming in in defense of Jiri on this one. I think we should reopen. I've heard this question asked a few times and it never gets a thoughtful answer. As a community, we should compile an answer to this as it would be a valuable reference, regardless of how broad it may be.

Comment: A very similar question was asked on academia: [Graduate program focusing on DevOps](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15675/graduate-program-focusing-on-devops).

Comment: so far I can see an offering of one semester dedicated to ALM/DevOps: https://www.ti.bfh.ch/de/weiterbildung/weiterbildungsangebote/cas/alm/tabs/uebersicht.html

Comment: As of autumn 2019, the Stralsund University in Germany seeks for candidates to become Professor of "Cloud Computing and DevOps" https://www.academics.de/jobs/professur-w2-cloud-computing-und-devops-hochschule-stralsund-stralsund-1004300

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really familiar with the topics you mentioned. However I went ahead to go checkout [kuleuven.be](http://www.kuleuven.be/english), i.e its Computer Science departement (with sufficient credibility, trust me).

Here are some interesting articles in which DevOps is mentioned:

- [Automated workflow regression testing for multi-tenant SaaS: Integrated support in self-service configuration dashboard](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/handle/123456789/548791).

  Here is part of the abstract of it:

  > ... This effectively makes these tenant administrators part of the **DevOps** team, and in turn creates the need for the SaaS provider to provide them with Quality Assurance tool support. One such tool is a regression testing framework that allows them to make sure that a new version of a workflow can behave similarly as to a successful execution of a previous version. ...
- [Variability middleware for multi-tenant SaaS applications](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/handle/123456789/500608).

  Here is part of the abstract of it:

  > ... The focus has been mainly on (1) the pre-deployment phases of the development life cycle and (2) fine-grained (tenant-level), run-time activation of specific variants. However, with upcoming trends such as **DevOps** and continuous delivery and deployment, operational aspects become increasingly important. ...

Both articles have links with contact info to their authors.